# How to access the public properties of a qml page loaded through a Loader?

Tags: qt, qml, loader, qt-quick

AA.qml

```
Item
{
    id:             drawLinesOnC

    property string  lineColour
    property int     lineDrawingSourceType
    property variant startEndPointArray

}
```

main.qml

```
Loader
{
   id:     drawLineLoaderA
   source: "AA.qml"
}
```

-

How to access the public properties of `AA.qml` page loaded through Loader `drawLineLoaderA`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution is as follows:

```
drawLineLoaderA.source = "DrawLineLoader.qml"
if (drawLineLoaderA.status == Loader.Ready)
{
    if (drawLineLoaderA.item && drawLineLoaderA.item.lineColour)
    {
        drawLineLoaderA.item.lineColour            = "black"
        drawLineLoaderA.item.lineDrawingSourceType = 2 
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend to be more carefully here. **First,** do all assignment in `onLoaded` of your Loader. **Second,** recheck weather your item has respective properties by doing `if (drawLineLoaderA.item && drawLineLoaderA.item.lineColour) { ... }`.

Comment: You can add it to your answer

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @TheIndependentAquarius said, you can declare property of the corresponding type in your loader:

```
Loader {
    id: drawLineLoaderA
    readonly property AA aa: item
    source: "AA.qml"
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
if (drawLineLoaderA.aa) {
    drawLineLoaderA.aa.color = "black"
}
```

Now you clearly stated that you deal with item of type AA and no other, and you'll get autocompletion on loaded item's properties as a bonus.

---

**Note 1**: Configuration of loaded item's properties should be done either in AA.qml itself (default values) or in Loader's onLoaded handler, as @troyane suggested.

**Note 2**: In your AA.qml you declared `property string lineColour`. You might be interested in `color` QML type. If you declare `property color lineColour`, QML will check that you assign valid values to this property. Moreover, `color` value is automatically converted to QColor when passed to C++ (and *from* QColor when passed from C++, of course).